# Postmaster Hook Errors

Tags: postmaster

I am using postmaster 1.5.0 on 2.9.0 EE and with a hook installed at the end of a store purchase, and I want to trigger an email. But....

When I submit the order via store, I get the following errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array
Filename: libraries/Postmaster_base_api.php
Line Number: 184
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: drivers/Channel_data_utility.php
Line Number: 37
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /public_html/admin/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: libraries/Functions.php
Line Number: 446
```

Any ideas what might be causing this, or is there a bug in the hooks postmaster version with EE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postmaster Store hook is only for Store 1, thus the problem.